# How to drag attention to someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I found out badly answered/voted question:
[disable the F1 key for whole system](https://superuser.com/questions/436625/disable-the-f1-key-for-whole-system/436641)

And I hope it gets more attention, so the "best answer" could be the right one (the regedit thing). Just to help out people who googled it like I did! I wasted plenty of time debugging my program when I wondered why my F1 key didn't work anymore; I thought I had a bug somewhere, but then I remembered I disabled the F1 help-key many weeks ago!

Edit: I did vote that answer up, but it had -1 votes before i did so. I also edited the answer to make it more pleasing to l33t people.

Comment: I see answers like what you linked, and could not define for the questioner that any one of them are "bad",  It completly depends on what your trying to do, and because the intent of the Q&A session being public, searchable and (more) open , many answers could be "good" even if they were not the exact one for that specific questioner.  I see "more is better" as long as the answers "work" as stated, and it is very usefull when people tell of the ramifications and actions of the method.

Comment: In the discussion, (possibly edited in later) there is this statement. ""which can be a pain because most help systems seem to take a while to load"   I see this as pertaining to more than just the windows help system, many of the larger programs use the same F1 and have slow loading Help systems too, that can vary in the style of help they use.  Disabling the one help system might not cover this questioners desires. In the same sence the questioner may find that one method or another is more usable even After they select a "accepted" answer.  More IS better.

Comment: @Psycogeek, the questioner doesnt care about the help system, like nobody does, if you want to find help, you use google these days, not some awkward help system which never works. Who would want to click some program on/off dozen of times in a day? There is absolutely no reason to say the other answers were better. I did upvote the correct answer, but it had -1 votes, so it didnt do much help. If the questioner would have asked "how to disable F1 key completely from my system so no program could ever use it?" then their answers could have been the right ones.

Answer (score 7):

If you agree the question is badly answered or voted, and you've acknowledged that the answer containing `regedit` code is the right one, why haven't you voted it up yet?

Ever since joining Super User, a year and seven months ago, you've only voted 9 times – but voting is the essential way of letting others know what's useful and what is not, so please [exercise your right](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to do so and vote more. You can vote as much as 30 times per day, and 10 times more on questions.

If you want to draw more attention to an answer, you can also [place a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the question and reward the existing answer. There's a dedicated bounty reason for that purpose.

[image]

Comment: I did vote it up, unfortunately it had -1 votes when i did so. I also edited that answer to make it drag less negative attention; the solution was good in itself, but there was minor problem which many seemed to dislike; so they just downvoted and agreed the other answers were better, instead of just editing the badly written but best answer like i did. I tried to find bounty button, but couldnt. Probably need more score to do so?

Comment: I see – as you can imagine, we can't see who voted for what exactly. See my updated answer on where to find the bounty link.

Comment: Weird, now i see it. I must been temporarily blind when i tried to find it first time? Does the accepted bounty move the answer up in the list? Or do you mean it just gives attention to the question?

Comment: Primarily it will draw attention on the question. If you award the the bounty in a week, the answer will have a mark next to it. Also, all the answers might be getting votes due to the increased number of views.